# Can I just copy/paste Laravel framework folder structure?

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel

My website already have MVC architecture. I want to expand his capabilities by installing Laravel framework.

Can I just copy unzipped Laravel framework, so all folders and libraries are just copy/pasted.  ?

I have VPS Ubuntu 12.04 and PHP 5.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In which form your website has MVC architecture implemented ?
Is that through your plain PHP code or through some other framework ?
Laravel is implementing MVC architecture on its own way. In order to use that Laravel MVC capabilities, you will have to move all your logic inside Laravel.

UPDATE WITH SOME RESOURCES:

[Official Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs)
[Laracasts - video lessons](https://laracasts.com/)
[Laravel IRC channel.](http://laravel.io/chat)

Good luck

Comment: Well someone have installed localhost with Laravel for me, but i didn't use much of libraries or similar, I was front-end developer, my job was mostly public folder. Now I want to bring website on higher level and to learn advanced PHP and Laravel. So question is can I just copy/paste that project folder without some special instalation....

Comment: great - Laravel is awesome. I'll update my post and provide you some links to get you started. The best way to do something with Laravel is to dig deeper - you wont regret.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have used MVC does not mean that it will fit laravel's structure unfortunatelly. With different file structure, routing, controllers and models it wont work that way.

I dont know how advanced and expanded your page is, but you will probably re-write it laravel way. 
Steps that you will need (assuming that you have some knowlege about laravel):

1. Prepare models for your existing database
2. Add routes for pages that you will need, create controllers for them using models
3. If you have used smarty templates, you can install smarty bundle for laravel, otherwise you will have re-write you templaets to blade (default laravel's templating engine)